# pytubeでダウンロードできなくなった

Tags: python

pytubeを使うスクリプトを作成してyoutubeから動画ファイルをダウンロードしている者です。
昨日まで順調にダウンロードできていたのですが、突然できなくなりました。
Pycharmでスクリプトを実行してみると
動画ファイルをダウンロードするところでエラーメッセージが出ました。
つまり、

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?**********')

で、YouTubeオブジェクトを作成し

print(yt.title + 'をダウンロード中 ...\n')

でタイトルは正常に表示されます。しかし、

yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first().download(
dl_path
)

のところまで来たところで、プロセスがストップし

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'

というメッセージが出ます。

昨日は60本ほどの番組を自動的に連続でダウンロードしました。
数日ほど前にも同じぐらいの本数を同じようにダウンロードしました。
その時は何の問題もなかったのですが、
今日になってダウンロードしようとするとエラーとなってしまいます。
pytubeをインストールしなおしても駄目です。

実は、当初youtube-dlを使ってダウンロードしていたのですが、
複数の番組を同時にダウンロードすることを繰り返している間に
ダウンロード速度が極端に遅くなり、ダウンロードの意味がなくなってきたのでpytubeに乗り換えたという経緯があります。
youtube-dlでは、あまりにも多く同時にダウンロードしようとしたのがまずかったのかと思い、今回は複数を同時にダウンロードすることはやめ、自動的に1本ずつ連続してダウンロードすることにしました。でもこういう結果になりました。

解決方法はありませんか。

なお、私は、１年ぐらい前からプログラムを独習で始めたものです。
だから、あまり詳しい知識はありません。
御指導よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

コードを変更していなのであれば、おそらくYouTubeの仕様が変更され、それに伴って動作しなくなったと思うのでpytubeライブラリのアップデートをしてみて下さい。
最新の物にしたい場合 `$ python -m pip install pytube` からだとまだ最新バージョンが適用されていない可能性があるので、GitHubのリポジトリを指定して更新する事をお勧めします。

```
$ python -m pip install git+https://github.com/pytube/pytube
```